# No checkbox let me to choose to reindex in enterprise

Tags: magento-enterprise, reindex

i had been using community version there will be a column of checkbox let me to reindex what i want see the pic

[image]

but in enterprise, there is no checkboxs

[image]

Anyone knows?

Comment: In enterprise indexing running in cron for those who haven't checkbox. you need to configure cron then it will reindex data by cron

Comment: check answer here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3912/cant-reindex-catalog-category-product-index-via-admin

Comment: @hkguile   following my be helpful for you http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/33868/3895